# Delete a database model in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I recently made 'Plan.create' from the heroku rails console.  It produced an empty `id 1`.  I then proceeded to enter the following:

```
>Plan.create(name: 'basic', ', price: 0)
>Plan.create(name: 'pro", price: 10)
```

After which, I have the following:

```
id1 -empty, id2 -basic, 0, id3 -pro, 10
```

I need to have `basic` in `id1` and `pro` in `id2`.  I was told I could just use `destroy.all` and re-enter my data.  This didn't work, and now I have `id 4` as the basic plan and `id 5` as the pro plan.

This is my question... how can I just redo that Plan model to start over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you're using postgresql. If yes, then this should help:

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE plans RESTART IDENTITY")
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-truncate.html

Comment: @sergio_tulentsev...  Thank you for the help... worked like a charm.  And yes, I am using postgresql.

Comment: Seems that you're new to stackoverflow. If an answer was helpful, you should accept it (the green checkmark on the left)

Answer (score 0):

You can just truncate the table.

In mysql

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE plans")
```

In Postgresql

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE plans RESTART IDENTITY;")
```

It will start your id from 1 again. Now you can recreate the plans.

Comment: Truncate Table will clean the old data and it will start the indexing from 1 again.

Comment: While true for mysql, it will not reset the sequences (by default) in postgresql. He's on heroku, so I'm willing to bet he's using postgres.

Comment: yes you are right as heroku supports only postgresql.